# Handling null values in NHibernate LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate

I've got an NHibernate query that looks like this:

```
var users = from u in _session.Query<User>();
            select new
                   {
                       u.FirstName
                       u.LastName,
                       u.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Group.GroupId == id).EmailAddress
                   }
```

However, if the user does not have a group with the specified ID, instead of defaulting the `EmailAddress` property to null, NHibernate throws the following error:

`` Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown [.Select[MyProject.Data.Entities.User,<>f__AnonymousType0`3[
...[Snipped] ``

It seems to be choking on the missing UserGroup entity.

If I modify this query so that a new UserGroup entity is created if one wasn't found (shown below), it stops the error from occurring and the data is returned, but seems like a hack when I actually just want this to default to null (as it would in Entity Framework) without having to instantiate a new UserGroup object.

```
var users = from u in _session.Query<User>();
            select new
                   {
                       u.FirstName
                       u.LastName,
                       EmailAddress = (u.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Group.GroupId == id) ?? new UserGroup()).EmailAddress
                   }
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var users = (from u in _session.Query<User>();
            select new
                   {
                       u.FirstName
                       u.LastName,
                       EmailAddress = u.UserGroups.Where(x => x.Group.GroupId == id)
                                                  .Select(x => x.EmailAddress)
                                                  .FirstOrDefault()
                   }).ToList();
```

First you add the condition with `Where` method, after this you change the output with `Select` method  to get only the `EmailAddress` column and finally you call `FirstOrDefault`.

Remember to check if `EmailAddress` is not `null` before using it.